# Fuzzy Clustering in R

Tags: r, correlation

I am very new to [r](/questions/tagged/r) and statistics..

I have dataset that contains 4 columns of data:

```
Incident                 Lat       Long           ClosedDate
Construction Noise     1.324      1.44          29/03/2011
Smell                  1.324      1.525         29/02/2009
Accident               1.323      1.424         29/01/2012
```

A correlation matrix is generated by combining spatial and temporal correlation. Incident clustering was done using Hierarchical Agglomerative Clustering (HAC). Sample code shown below:

```
hc_issues <- hclust(as.dist(inverse_cc_combined), "complete")
plot(hc_issues, cex=0.8, hang=-1)

###Automatically cut the dendrogram
require(dynamicTreeCut)
ct_issues <- cutreeHybrid(hc_issues, inverse_cc_combined, minClusterSize=5)
```

Now that I need to find to probabilities of data elements across multiple clusters and I want to use fuzzy clustering.

Below is the desired output

```
Incident           Cluster_1_Prob  Cluster_2_Prob  Cluster_3_Prob
Incident_1         0.52            0.5             0.4
Incident_2         0.32            0.5             0.9
```

How can I achieve this in R (using Fanny or any other method)?

Comment: FANNY <- fanny(as.dist(inverse_cc_combined),, k = 3, maxit = 2000)
FANNY$membership
 
MDS <- smacofSym(distMat)$conf
 
plot(MDS, type = "n")
text(MDS, label = rownames(MDS), col = rgb((FANNY$membership)^(1/1)))

Comment: I have a correlation matrix object ( inverse_cc_combine) instead of using Hclust .. i want to use fuzzy clustering method so that i can create clusters and find probabilities of data elements across multiple clusters